# Get current URL with Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to write a Chrome extension that will take the URL of the page the user is on and send it to a server for a response back.

So far I have been trying to use `chrome.tabs.getCurrent()`, but I get uncaught TypeError on the getCurrent object.

Is there an easy way for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getSelected is deprecated. The preferred way to access the current tab is:

```
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true}, function(tab) {
        // Do stuff here
    }
```

Comment: Still its going for the extension tab

Answer (score 3):

Any reason why you don't want to use [`getSelected()`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html)?

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(windowId, function(tab) {
    alert("current:"+tab.url);
});
```

Comment: For the same reason that getCurrent() doesn't work...  I'm trying to get a chrome extension to grab the URL of the current page...

Comment: @HatchiNZ Maybe you are not calling it at the right place? Where do you put this code?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because getCurrent returns the tab the script is running on, not the tab that is currently selected.

You should probably be using getSelected as noted by serg